# Is thinking-sphinx needed for full-text search with PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, thinking-sphinx

I used thinking-sphinx (and flying-sphinx on Heroku) and mySQL in Rails 3 app. Now that I migrated to PostgreSQL, I would like to know:

- Do I need thinking-sphinx or I can implement all thinking-sphinx functions on PostgreSQL?
- What thinking-sphinx can do that I can't with PostgreSQL, since the latter supports full-text search as well?

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL does support fulltext search indexing, but Sphinx is faster.  It's a few years old, but you can check out my presentation [Full Text Search In PostgreSQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/full-text-search-in-postgresql) in which I compare several solutions.

Advantages of using PostgreSQL FTS:

- It's built-in, no need to run another technology.
- The index is automatically in sync with your data, no need to import data to the index periodically.
- Much easier to support incremental updates.

Advantages of using Sphinx Search:

- Better bottom-line query performance.
- Somewhat easier to understand indexing.
- Offloads search traffic from the RDBMS, so you can scale more easily in theory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. The summary is very nice as well. I am very interested in your opinion about performance of PostgreSQL today, as its proponents say it improves performance very quickly after each release.

Comment: @AdamNYC, good question, I agree it's worth doing some tests with the current version, but I don't have PostgreSQL installed right now.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'll use thinking-sphinx with PostgreSQL for now, since I already have it in place.